# ORDER BY clause constrained by a sub-selection in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have kind of a edge-case while working on a WordPress project. I am using Advanced Custom Fields to store metadata about posts, which is stored in a "postmeta" table (whereas posts are stored in a "post" table; here prefixed by "otca_").

The posts here are events, which feature a mandatory evt_date and *may* feature a evt_date_fin ("fin" stands for "end" in French, sorry about the lame naming convention).

My goal is to select a range of events, keeping only those featuring a evt_date set in the future OR a evt_date_fin set in the future (in the latter case, no matter the evt_date), while ordering by evt_date, so as to display them in a paginated, sorted way.

This is what I came up with:

```php
$today = date('Ymd');
$perPage = 12;
$offset = $perPage * ($paged-1); // $paged equals 1, 2, … n (the current page)

$querystr = "
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM otca_posts AS post
INNER JOIN otca_postmeta AS meta ON (post.ID = meta.post_id)
WHERE post.post_type = 'agenda'
AND post.post_status = 'publish'
AND (
     (meta.meta_key = 'evt_date'     AND CAST(meta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '". $today ."')
  OR (meta.meta_key = 'evt_date_fin' AND CAST(meta.meta_value AS CHAR) >= '". $today ."')
)
ORDER BY (meta.meta_key = 'evt_date' AND CAST(meta.meta_value AS CHAR)) ASC
LIMIT ". $perPage ." OFFSET ". $offset;

$evts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
$total = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()');

// then looping over the $evts and using $perPage / $total to build the pagination links
```

So, for a given post stored in otca_post, there are several records in the otca_postmeta table referencing this post (using post_id), which differ by their meta_key / meta_value pairs (one pair for evt_date, another for evt_date_fin). I use them to filter out posts in the query, which works fine.

The ORDER BY clause does not actually works though.

I would like to know how I could make it so that the posts are ordered by evt_date, a piece of information stored in otca_postmeta; evt_date is not a row, but rather a value stored in the row "meta_key", which means I need to perform a sub-selection somehow in order to… order.

Thank you.

Comment: Would you mind in setting a small set of data and from it your desired result? Even better it would be you create a sqlfiddle with it. 100% sure you will get answers faster.

Comment: It looks like you're missing half of a boolean expression with the `CAST()`. Do you mean to compare that to some value? The `AND` is going to result in a positive boolean return for any non-null value of `CAST(meta.meta_value AS CHAR)` in your order by.

Comment: I _think_ you might be looking for something like `ORDER BY CASE WHEN meta.meta_key = 'evt_date' THEN CAST(meta.meta_value AS CHAR) ELSE NULL END ASC` to conditionally match `evt_date` and sort on its CHAR cast `meta_value`. Use a high value like `ZZZ` in place of `NULL` if the non-matches are sorting first but you want them last...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Didn't know about sqlfiddle, I'll use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this fairly often in my WordPress plugins - you need to join the `posts` table to the `postmeta` table for each of the `meta_key`'s that you care about, in this case "evt_date" and "evt_date_fin". Once you have joined them you can use them in the `WHERE` clause to compare to `DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`. Using the MySql function [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) will convert the strings stored in the `meta_value` to a `DATE` datatype - this example assumes you use a `Y-m-d` format.

```
$perPage = 12;
$offset = $perPage * ($paged-1);

// create the SQL query by joining posts to postmeta
$querystr = <<<SQL
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
        p.*, 
        STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') AS start_date, 
        STR_TO_DATE(e.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') AS end_date
    FROM otca_posts AS p
    -- join postmeta for the start
    JOIN otca_postmeta AS s ON p.ID = s.post_id AND s.meta_key = 'evt_date'
    -- join postmeta for the end
    JOIN otca_postmeta AS e ON p.ID = e.post_id AND e.meta_key = 'evt_date_fin'
    WHERE 
        -- is the start greater than or equal to today?
        STR_TO_DATE(s.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) OR
        -- or is the end greater than or equal to today?
        STR_TO_DATE(e.meta_value, '%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    -- order the results by the start, then the end, then the post title
    ORDER BY start_date, end_date, p.post_title
    -- paginate the results
    LIMIT $perPage OFFSET $offset
SQL;

// get posts that match
$evts = $wpdb->get_results( $querystr );

// get the total number of results
$total = $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' );
```

Comment: Thank you doublesharp. I added the constraints about the post's type and status back within the query, edited the date casting format (no dash for me), and it does exactly what I want. I've learnt some SQL along the way.